# How to perform drill through on a card visual (respecting the filter context)?

Tags: powerbi

I have 3 visuals on report.

1. Card visual
2. Pie chart visual
3. Table visual

I have set up drill through on the pie chart visual. Clicking on pie area takes me to another page (drill through) respecting the filter context.

However there is no setting to perform drill through on the card visual. Is there any way to perform drill through on card visual (respecting the filter context)?

Answer (score 0):

You may set the Action for the button and link it to a bookmark or You may use 'sync slicer'.

p.s. If this (or another) answer helps you, please take a moment to "accept" the answer that helped by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from "greyed out" to "filled in". :)

Comment: If I use bookmark approach, then it will always show the view which was bookmarked. It would not have the filter context. Any way to have this?